# Binary Search in Go - why the heck is this incorrect

Tags: go, binary-search

Cant figure out why the heck is this incorrect implementation of Binary Search in go.
Input is `([]int{-1, 0, 3, 5, 9, 12}, 9)`

```
func Search(nums []int, target int) int {

    mid := len(nums) / 2

    if nums[mid] == target {
        return mid
    }
    if len(nums) >= 1 {
        if nums[mid] < target {
            return Search(nums[mid+1:], target)
        } else {
            return Search(nums[:mid], target)
        }
    }

    return -1
}
```

Answer (score 6):

## Binary Search

### Updated to fix infinite recursion

Thanks @sprutex for finding the bug

```
func Search(nums []int, target int) int {
    mid := len(nums) / 2

    if nums[mid] == target {
        return mid
    }
    if len(nums) > 1 {
        if nums[mid] < target {
            res := Search(nums[mid:], target)
            if res == -1 {
                return -1
            }
            return res + mid
        } else {
            return Search(nums[:mid], target)
        }
    }

    return -1
}
```

### Original answer

DO NOT USE - contains infinite recursion bug when searching
for an item not in the list.

```
func Search(nums []int, target int) int {

    mid := len(nums) / 2

    if nums[mid] == target {
        return mid
    }
    if len(nums) >= 1 {
        if nums[mid] < target {
            return Search(nums[mid:], target) + mid
        } else {
            return Search(nums[:mid], target)
        }
    }

    return -1
}
```

The one line that was changed is the following:

`return Search(nums[mid:], target) + mid`

Comment: Really did not understand this change. If value of mid is less than target, then I am just using from index of mid+1 (inclusive) to end to look for target again. Why would you add +mid at the add and change [mid+1] to mid.

Comment: Because the recursive call is based off a sub-slice. Searching this smaller sub-slice needs the original offset (`mid`) re-added for it to refer to the correct index.

Comment: This does not work with a case when a target is not presented within a slice, e.g. `nums = []int{1, 2, 5, 7, 9, 16}, target = 3`. Be careful this solution goes to infinite recursion

Comment: @sprutex Thanks for finding the bug. I updated the answer with the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say, your slice is `nums=[5,12,17,20,30,39,55,67]`. Your target number is 55. When you make a recursive call on the right side of the array in the line `return Search(nums[mid:], target)`, the new slice is `nums=[30,39,55,67]`. The index of 55 was 6 in the original slice but in the new slice, it is 2. That is why you are not getting the correct answer.

When you make a new slice from an existing slice, the index of the elements does not reflect the old slice. To make this up you need to add the current `mid` when you are selecting the right side of the slice for binary search.

Comment: That is a crucial bit that I completely missed. Thank you both you guys